# OCR to return size of FEW words only inside image

Tags: .net, ocr, tessnet2

Is there any OCR tool to read coordinates **of only some words** inside an image. For e.g. refer attached image, I require coordinate of only two words, namely,
1)"Measurements"
2) "999999.9mi" [image]

Is this achievable?

I could think of passing required words as input to any OCR tool like Tessnet2, but did not find any suitable function ?
Any other suggestions would help..

Comment: can you be more specific? For example, you can show us what you need with images or examples.

Comment: @jackjop, I have added an image for clarity, kindly respond. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. I would need to loop through the words detected by Tessnet2 tool to match the words I want. This would resolve my issue.

However, I noticed that the Tessnet2 tool is not reading words correctly. The above image should return following words: 
1)Trailer Blind Spot 
2) Measurements
3) have been saved
4) 999999.9mi

But Tessnet2 returns following , **which is wrong.**..

1)Trailer 
2) Blind 
3) Spot 
4) Measurements
5) have 
6) been 
7) saved

Can someone help here?